# Confusion regarding Stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I've a stupid doubt in the construction of stochastic integral of real scalar valued maps. Many times I've seen in books after the stochastic integral is defined in **[$0,T$]**  for the integrand in $L^2$  where $E(\int_{0}^{T}f(s)^2ds)<\infty$ we again use localization technique to extend the stochastic integral to  more general processes $P(\int_{0}^{T}f(s)^2ds<\infty)=1 $. My questions are

1. For a finite measure space if a random variable  is almost everywhere finite then does not it mean that it expectation is finite? That too when I work in [$0,T$] not in [$0,\infty$]
2. Can someone give me a counter example stating that a function belonging to the more general localization-technique defined space and not into the $L^2$ space.

I'm omitting the details as these are very standard and can be found in text books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *almost surely finite* does not imply *integrable*. Consider a random variable $X$ exponential with parameter $1$ and $Y=\mathrm e^X$. Then $X$ is almost surely finite hence $Y$ is almost surely finite but, for every $y\geqslant1$, $\mathrm P(Y\geqslant y)=\mathrm P(X\geqslant\log y)=\mathrm e^{-\log y}=1/y$, hence $Y$ is not integrable.

Comment: The chain is bounded P-a.s. -> integrable -> finite expectation -> finite P-a.s. right?